# It's possible to get only the elements inside a specific element using document.querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

So I have a function that looks like this:

```js
function myFunc(targetElements, otherThings... ){
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(targetElements);
//...
//otherThings...
}
```

But sometimes instead of have the function performing in the elements of the whole document I need this function to access only the elements inside a specific element that I already have outside the function like this:

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('#mySpecificUl');
//should use myFunc(childsOfUl, otherThings... ) to perform in the elements "a" inside "ul"
```

I was wondering if its possible to do that without have to change the function that I already have, something that could look like this:

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('#mySpecificUl');
myFunc(ul > "a", otherThings...); //like this or something
```

To be more clear what I want to know is if it's possible to limite the range of the **document.querySelectorAll()** to it perform only in the specific children of a element,
something that would works just like:

```js
ul.querySelectorAll()
```

but with

```js
document.querySelectorAll()
```

It could look like **document.querySelectorAll(ul > "a");** or something.

Thanks to anyone who take the time.

Comment: the `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` methods use `CSS syntax` to target DOM elements. So as long as you provide correct css syntax you can target whatever you want. Like `document.querySelectorAll('ul > a')` for example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Elements have](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-parentnode-queryselectorall%E2%91%A0) the `querySelectorAll` method too:

```
let ul = document.querySelector('#mySpecificUl');
ul.querySelectorAll('a') // will contain all <a> descendants of #mySpecificUl
```

If you don't want to select the element first, you can do it in a single `querySelectorAll` with the descendant selector (a space) or the child selector (`>`):

```
// children
document.querySelectorAll('#mySpecificUl > a')
```

```
// all descendants
document.querySelectorAll('#mySpecificUl a')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers but what I was looking for is a alternative to this ul.querySelector using the document.querySelector, I even coted it in the end of the question

Comment: @KleberGermano if your "parent" element, the element where you want to start the search, itself has an id or a unique class, then you can do it via a simple selector. You have not made clear why exactly you don't want to explicitly do what's suggested in this answer.

Comment: Tks a lot @CeratinPerformance, the second part was what I was looking for

Comment: @Pointy the anwers was edited, the second added part was exacly what I was looking